# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first?

Tags: android, removechild

```
Add Dynamic EditText with is this code but i got exception.
```

When i Click added edittext it give another row but i got illegalstate Exception.This is my code.

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    final View callRowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.call_field,null);
                    callParent.addView(callRowView);
                    EditText editText = callRowView.findViewById(R.id.call_e_text);

                    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                            callParent.addView(callRowView);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

please help me to solve this problem. 
Thank You,

Comment: you are trying to add same view to the layout twice. You can't do that. You need to inflate a new view to add

Comment: first time callrowview can add single edittext next time i click the added edittext it will give another row how to do that

Comment: Inflate it each time you need another row, as I said

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you can not add the view inside this method, this method may be called more than once and it is not necessary to add the view more than one time.

You should drop that line and invert the `addView()` method. Check below.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                final View callRowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.call_field,null);
                EditText editText = callRowView.findViewById(R.id.call_e_text);
                callParent.addView(callRowView);

                editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: if i click EditText editText = callRowView.findViewById(R.id.call_e_text); this i can add R.layout.call_field.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? May you edit your answer and post your full code?